# WPF put XAML refrences into a c# list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Right now I have 15 items, that I have to set the value to one by one, is there a way I can put all the refrences into one c# list or something, so I could loop through it?

```
//TITLES
BTitle0.Text = Items[14]["title"];
BTitle1.Text = Items[13]["title"];
BTitle2.Text = Items[12]["title"];
BTitle3.Text = Items[11]["title"];
BTitle4.Text = Items[10]["title"];
BTitle5.Text = Items[9]["title"];
BTitle6.Text = Items[8]["title"];
BTitle7.Text = Items[7]["title"];
BTitle8.Text = Items[6]["title"];
BTitle9.Text = Items[5]["title"];
BTitle10.Text = Items[4]["title"];
BTitle11.Text = Items[3]["title"];
BTitle12.Text = Items[2]["title"];
BTitle13.Text = Items[1]["title"];
BTitle14.Text = Items[0]["title"];
```

Basically I want to have a list to XAML refrences like BTitle[0].text..., Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are those `TextBox`es? What is their parent container/element?

Comment: Use an ItemsControl. Put the TextBlock into its ItemTemplate. Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). What you are doing now is the wrong approach.

Comment: @thatguy Those are TextBlocks, their parent container is a Canvas

Answer (score -1):

Try the [FindName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) method of the window or control that hosts the `TextBox` elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    TextBox textBox = FindName("BTitle" + i) as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Text = "...";
    }
}
```

Or use an [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) that binds to the items.

Comment: @IgnasMikolaitis: Did you try this or what happened?